# Sockets: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a class where i listen for connections in a separated thread, my problem is that when i try close the socket, comes a exception in **`Socket.Accept();`** that says:

> A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall

After a seach, i understood that probably this is because i'm closing the socket from another thread (in my case this thread is UI). How i can close and open the socket correctly anytime?

**Listener**

```
class Listener
{

    private Socket s;
    private bool listening = false;

    public bool Running
    {
        get { return listening; }
    }

    public Listener()
    {
       s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    }

    public void BeginListen(int port)
    {
        s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
        s.Listen(100);
        listening = true;

        while (listening)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = s.Accept();
        }
    }

    public void StopListen()
    {
        if (listening == true)
        {
            s.Close();
            listening = false;
        }

    }

}
```

**frmMain**

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{

private Listener listener;

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listener = new Listener();
}

private void listen()
{
   listener.BeginListen(101);
}

private void stopToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listener.StopListen();
}

private void tmrcheck_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listener.Running)
    {
        startToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        stopToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
    }

    if (!listener.Running)
    {
        startToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        stopToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @jdweng, to always wait for a new client.

Comment: @jdweng, `while(true){ ... }` is need to accept more than one connection. Without this, will accept only first connection and exit.

Comment: Not true. Not true.

Comment: @jdweng, How no? exists several code examples that shows this :-).

Comment: Doesn't mean it will work in your case.  Using Synchronous mode you need to get each socket so the while loop is needed so you can return data.  But your code will only get the last connection since you have on one socket.  Second you are blocked when using Synchronous mode which is giving an exception.  The error is occurring because you got the first connection but then you are blocked waiting for more connections.  Recommend you go to the Asynchronous Listener.